# How does one list the changes via the API from a TeamCity build?

Tags: api, rest, teamcity

I'm trying to find a way to get all the comments from a particular build in TeamCity via the Rest API. How can one do that?

Answer (score 10):

```
http://teamcity:port/httpAuth/app/rest/changes?locator=build:(id:77651)&fields=count,change:(version,username,date,href,comment,files)
```

Via this URL, one can list out in custom fashion exactly the fields they wish to return. I don't think this is documented, i got this from their support folks. Enjoy!

PS - There are other examples out there which iterate over each change, this lists out all the changes for a particular build id in one place, for parsing.